# calling a function from inside a constructor variable giving undefiend error in javascript

Tags: javascript

the code :

```
function CreateDiv(D) {

        D.width = this.width;
        D.height = this.height;
        D.position = "absolute";
        D.bottom = 0;
        D.right = function () { };
        D.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        D.data = function () {
            return "this is data of Div" + D.id;
        };
        D.create = function () {
            var divToAppend = "<div id='" + D.id + "' style='border:1px solid black;width:20;height:20;'  >" + D.data + "</div>";
            return divToAppend;
           // $("#Container").append(divToAppend);
        };
    }

    function NewChat() {
        var divv = new CreateDiv({width:200,height:200});
        alert(divv.create); // undefiend 
    }
```

can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: And what and where exactly is the error?

Comment: the alert is giving me undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up `D.` and `this.` in your class definition:

```
function CreateDiv(D) {

    this.width = D.width;
    this.height = D.height;
    this.position = "absolute";
    this.bottom = 0;
    this.right = function () { };
    this.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    this.data = function () {
        return "this is data of Div" + this.id;
    };
    this.create = function () {
        var divToAppend = "<div id='" + this.id + "' style='border:1px solid black;width:20;height:20;'  >" + this.data + "</div>";
        return divToAppend;
       // $("#Container").append(divToAppend);
    };
}
```

When you create a new object using the `new` operator and a function, inside that constructor function you reference the created object by using `this`.

In your code you just extend the given parameter `D`, which is never returned.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `D.create`; 
you should use `this.create`

```
this.create = function () {
            var divToAppend = "<div id='" + D.id + "' style='border:1px solid black;width:20;height:20;'  >" + D.data + "</div>";
            return divToAppend;
           // $("#Container").append(divToAppend);
        };
```